# Calling a function from server-side on the client-side (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, client

I have the following code on the server:

```
var game = io.listen(app);

game.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    storePlayers(socket.id);
    //Only the player the connects gets this message
    socket.emit('firstTime', {message: 'Welcome!'});

    //If a player disconnects, a message will be sent to all the sockets.
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        game.sockets.emit('exit', {message: 'Player ' + socket.id + ' left the game...!'});
    });

    //When a player connects, all the players will get this message.
    game.sockets.emit('entrance', {message: 'Player ' + socket.id + ' is online'});
});
```

I want to get a hold of the `storePlayers(id)` function. The reason for this being when a socket connects, an object is supposed to be created with the specific `socket.id` on the client-side.

How would I go about doing such a thing?

Comment: emit that ID to the client?

Comment: @HamzaKubba yes - basically. And use that when I create an object on the client side

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @HamzaKubba Ideally I would like to get a hold of the function storePlayers(id) from the client side of something like that is possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "get a hold of"?

Comment: Do you mean this:
`socket.emit('firstTime', {message: 'Welcome!', socket_id: storePlayers(socket.id);});`

Comment: @HamzaKubba Ill try this - thanks! Ill let you know

Comment: @HamzaKubba I've encoutered a different problem - Have a look if you'd like.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390905/accessing-a-function-stored-in-an-object-on-server-side-from-client-side/19391142?noredirect=1#19391142

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want the client to send an `id` when it connects to your server.You can achieve this by sending a message once the client connects to your server.

**Client side**

```
var socket = io.connect('your_server')    
socket.on('connect', function () {
        clientId = generate_id(); //however you want to generate the id
        socket.emit('newUser', {id: clientId});
    }
```

You can then capture the message 'newUser' on the server and retrieve the id of the connected client.